# How to draw png image in mono without references to X11

Tags: c#, linux, mono, drawing, png

I have a micro Linux in embedded system and there is no GUI. I need to create png images with some simple geometry and text labels.
Standard System.Drawing in Mono refers to X11 libraries which I do not have on my device. If I have understood it right, Mono.Cairo refers to X11 too.

Is it any standalone drawing library or some other way to create .png image without some heavy references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Mono.Cairo](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cairo/). It doesn't depend on X11 (in my case I build system with [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) tool).

Answer (score 0):

Not really. On non-Windows systems GDI+ depends on Cairo, not the other way around. So Cairo is the way to go.

Comment: Oh, I'm sory, I was wrong. I meant "X11" instead of "GDI+". I just have edited my post.

Comment: It should be possible to build Cairo without X11, but that might be too complex. Can you run Xvfb on your target? It is a "virtual X11" server that behaves just like X11 but does not output graphics.